# Attach User to Django ModelForm / FormView after submit

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a FormView CBV (shows a ModelForm) that is working fine. However, I now want to append a "created_by" attribute to the form, upon saving it to the database. This "created_by" field should be the current, logged-in user, who has filled out the form.

I have tried delaying `form.save()`, appending the `request.user` and then saving everything...but the page just redirects to itself, and the model data isn't added. Thoughts?

Relevant **models.py**:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    submitted_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Date Submitted')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    event_date = models.DateField()
```

Relevant **views.py**:

```
class PostEventView(FormView):
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = "event-submit.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.created_by = self.request.user
        form.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Your event was submitted successfully. Thank you for taking the time to add this opportunity!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('single_event', kwargs={'slug': form.slug}))
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried [overriding the save function](http://trickveda.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/overriding-save-method-in-django-models/)? That link helps.

Comment: Are you sure the form is valid? You probably need to exclude `created_by` from the EventForm.

Comment: @DanielRoseman...totally missed it, as adding in `created_by` was an afterthought. I hadn't excluded it from the ModelForm. That solves it!

Comment: You should address why you weren't seeing the invalid error messages, though: you probably need to add `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` at the top of the form.

Comment: Bingo. Did it as soon as you made the other comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Daniel Roseman for pointing out that I had forgotten to `exclude = ['created_by']` from my `ModelForm`. Adding this field was an afterthought, and I had consequently forgotten to `exclude` it. My template was also missing `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`, which explained why I wasn't seeing any validation errors.